# How to divide block in piece when they overlap

Tags: bittorrent

Some input I'm looking to build a simple minimal bittorrent client.
I reading the protocol spec for a 2-3 days now.

here what my understanding on it thus far . Assuming that torrent has a **piece length** of `26000 bytes` and according to non official spec **block size** is `16384`. Something like this.

[image]
Now upon request of a block of piece message would look like this

```
piece 0 
block offset 0
block length 16484
```

So far so good.

Now, for next block which overlap in piece 0 and 1 what should the request look like

```
piece 0  ## since the start of byte is in piece 0 use piece 0 instead of piece 1
block offset 16384
block length 16384
```

Now on the receiving end I need to recreate the piece of 26000 bytes so that I can compare that with pieces (hash) to match the piece for correctness.

Is my understanding correct ?

Also I'm let suppose the piece verification failed and may be it because of the first block i.e Block 0 (which is faulty or corrupt)
then I should requeue Block 0 and Block 1 (which was valid btw and also a part of piece 1) to retransmit again.

And now suddenly the piece and block distribution become a bit complex then what I assume it be. and I hoping there is a simpler solution to this.

Any thought

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Last block in a piece may be smaller than the transfer block size. I.e. `26000 - 16384 = 9616` bytes should be requested in the second PIECE message. As soon as all `26000` bytes have been received, SHA-1 hash should be calculated and compared with the corresponding checksum from the `pieces` section of metainfo dictionary. If the checksum does not match, you have no means to know which block contained invalid data and should re-download all blocks from this piece.

My advice would be not to depend on some particular partitioning of the piece, because:
1) peers may use a different transfer block size when requesting data
2) SHA-1 algorithm is block-based, and the digester better use a bigger block size (otherwise calculations will take more time)

A proper abstraction for a piece would be a generic `data range` with the following methods:

- `read(from:int, length:int):byte[]`
- `write(offset:int, block:byte[]):()`

Then you'll be able to read/write arbitrary subranges of data.

Comment: Your Advice is not clear to me it seem to me that you are suggesting I consider a individual piece as a block and then download it. correct ?.

Comment: No, why? You were absolutely correct that you need to make 2 separate requests to fully receive a piece when the piece size is 2600 and the block size is 16384. However, you missed the fact that the piece length is not divisible by 16384, and thus the second block is truncated to just 9616 bytes.

Comment: Well 2 things first I went and google for the piece length value most torrent use. and I according to google I found all piece length info to be a divisible by 16384. Although I did not find a clear documentation mentioning it but still. So is this some sort of standard all torrent client follow to use a piece length that is divisible by 16384.

Comment: In fact it is mentioned in http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html: 'request' messages contain an index, begin, and length. The last two are byte offsets. Length is generally a power of two unless it gets truncated by the end of the file. All current implementations use 2^14 (16 kiB), and close connections which request an amount greater than that.

Comment: `1) peers may use a different transfer block size when requesting data`  assuming that a peers in the swarm use a different transfer block size.  Wouldn't this would hard for client to manage since each peer will now have a different bitfield representation and every time client need to request a payload it need to translate in block offset in accordance with the existing peer right?

Comment: You are confusing piece availability (which is represented by bitfields) and presence of "blocks" in a particular piece. Pieces are split into "blocks" solely for the purpose of transfer of data over the network. Hence, a block is nothing more than a transfer data unit, much like a network packet, just bigger. Each peer may choose which "packet" size to use, and 16384 bytes is just a common convention, but it's not mandatory at all.

Comment: Just like `bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html` the request length field as 2^14 (16Kib) is there any where I can found about piece length as well. All in all whether the happens to be `piece length` should be multiple of 16384 is something mention in any BEEP documentation.

Comment: can we connect over email I think I'm still few missing info in my head that I would like to discuss.

Comment: sure, feel free to send me a message

Comment: Thanks I will drop you a mail once I reach home. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Will use the more distinct term '*chunk*' instead of the ambiguous '*block*'.

---

- #### A torrent is divided into pieces.
- #### A piece is divided into chunks.
- #### A chunk is cut from one piece.

A torrent is divided into pieces when it's created. With the **Request** message, a piece is in turn further divided into chunks by the downloading BitTorrent client.
How the client cut the chunks out from a piece doesn't matter, as long as no single chunk is larger than 16 KB (16384 bytes).
The simplest and most rational way to divide a piece, is to do it in as few chunks as possible, by dividing it in 16 KB chunks and let the last chunk of the piece be smaller if necessary.

---

> The **Request** message format: `<len=0013><id=6><Piece_index><Chunk_offset><Chunk_length>`
>
> - `<Piece_index >` integer specifying the zero-based piece index
> - `<Chunk_offset>` integer specifying the zero-based byte offset within the piece
> - `<Chunk_length>` integer specifying the requested number of bytes

When requesting a chunk:

- **the whole chunk must be within the piece specified by the `Piece_index`**,
  ie `Chunk_offset`+`Chunk_length` must be less or equal to the size of that specific piece*.
- the `Chunk_length` can not be larger than 16 KB (16384 bytes) and must be at least 1 byte
- the peer that get the request must have the piece specified by the `Piece_index`

If any of the conditions is not met, the peer receiving the request will close the connection.

* For all pieces except the very last one that is the `'piece length'` defined in the *info*-dictionary.
The size of the last piece can by calculated as:
`size_last_piece = size_of_torrent - (number_of_pieces - 1) * 'piece length'`

Comment: Hello, So am I right to say that the initial request will look like: `<len=0013><id=6><0><0><16384>` followed by a 2nd request `<len=0013><id=6><0><16384><16384>` ... with `<Chunk_offset>` always increasing by `<Chunk_length>` up until `piece length`? After which we concat the `payloads` together and do a `sha` hash to see if it matches that of the metadata info?

Answer (score 0):

The *maximum* block size commonly accepted by clients is 16KiB. Clients are free to make smaller requests.

Pieces are commonly a multiple of 16KiB, but the current spec does not require it (this changes with [BEP52](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html)) and some people use prime numbers or similar things for fun, so they do exist in the wild.

Blocks only exist in the sense that you need multiple requests to get a complete piece that is larger than 16KiB. In other words, blocks are the same thing as whatever you decide to request. You could request 500 bytes, then 1017 bytes and then 13016 bytes, ... until you got a complete piece. They are arbitrary subdivisions *within a piece* - there is no overlap - that you need to keep track of between the start of downloading a piece and finishing the piece.

They do not participate in hashing, they do not factor into the HAVE or BITFIELD messages. Only REQUEST, PIECE, CANCEL and REJECT messages concern themselves with blocks. And instead of blocks you could also call them *sub-piece offset-length tuples* or something to that effect.